# Obj-c - Opening PDF in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm trying to open a PDF in my `UIWebView`. For some reason, when I pull the URL from an `NSString`, and then use the `NSString` in my code, the webview returns empty (even though the string contains url data). However, if I type the URL into `URLWithString` IN FULL (e.g. example.com/file.pdf), the PDF appears as it should. That said, the link to the PDF displayed is constantly different, which is why I'm using `NSString` to populate the `UIView`'s PDF link. Any idea why this isn't working?

**ViewController.m**

```
NSString *browserLink = self.linkProgram[@"body"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:browserLink];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes a URL is corrupted or has characters in it that a `UIWebView` will not recognize and thus will not show you the page/PDF that you are interested in. Try this, use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to try to remove any spaces and replace them with percent escapes that may be in the URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
[browserLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

This typically works, however I had issues in the past myself where this did not fix the issue for me. Instead I used the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` method to replace the characters.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: 
[browserLink stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString:@"%20"]];
```

---

**EDIT**

Brittany the issue for you is with [App Transport Security](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6767). Ensure that your `info.plist` file contains the following keys to apply your ATS settings:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>pdfpdf.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

[image]

With this change the following code will work for you.

```
NSString *browserLink = self.linkProgram[@"body"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:browserLink];
UIWebView * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

---

**RESULT**

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the URL so I can see it? Have you tried the second method?

Comment: Super strange, so when I use my code above, browserLink is populated with my clean URL. However, when I log 'url', it's NULL.

Comment: That is because it could not construct a valid NSURL object with the string you provided from `browserLink`. The first culprit would be that `browserLink` is not formatted correctly. What is the URL so I can try to load it in my `UIWebView`?

Comment: I've been using this as my test: http://www.pdfpdf.com/samples/Sample1.PDF

Comment: @Brittany If you see a `%0A` then that means you have a newline character in your URL. You need to strip that from your URL string before attempting to create the `NSURL` from the string.

Comment: @rmaddy I don't have %0A in my URL at all using my initial code above. I only see the %0A when I use the code provided by Brandon A.

Comment: @Brittany Yes, I know. The newline in your URL string gets translated to `%0A` when you add the percent escaping.

Comment: @Brittany I updated my answer with the fix to your problem.

Comment: I'm not typing the URL directly into the string... the string is what NSString *browserLink = self.linkProgram[@"body"]; returns. The above code still doesn't work when I utilize browserLink as the source of the PDF url. E.g. NSString *urlString = self.linkProgram[@"body"];

Comment: @Brittany OK... so you could have just replaced the part in my answer with the code you had and that would be the fix, but incase you can't do that I included that change in my answer above. This should work for you now.

Comment: @Brittany were you able to get this to work? It should be displaying for you now if you follow my answer. See image for what the result should look like.

Answer (score 0):

[image]This is how i use it -

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


NSString *urlString = _datadiction[@"doclink"];

    if(urlString != nil || [urlString isEqualToString:@""]){

        WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
        WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
        NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

        [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

        [webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];

    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Error");
    }

#P.S -  Update info.plist with Transport Security... (allow arbitary loads = YES)
```

Comment: So weird. Even after updating info.plist with allow arbitary loads, nsrequest still comes back as NULL. Though urlString comes back as a perfect URL. I'm stumped.

Comment: Check the updated answer with screenshot and try appliying those info.plist configuration